# Why doesn't the ScrollView display the TextView as a whole?

Tags: android, textview, scrollview

I have ScrollBar which contains a TextView, but the TextView is not shown completely.

How can I cause to TextView to expand to fill the ScrollView?

I have ScrollBar which contains a TextView, but the TextView is not shown completely.

How can I cause to TextView to expand to fill the ScrollView?

[image: Screenshot]

My XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/rootEditLayout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/ScrollViewDescribtion"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_gravity="right"
android:layout_margin="5dip"
android:layout_weight="99"
android:clipChildren="true"
android:fadeScrollbars="false"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:foregroundGravity="fill_vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/DescribtionLinearLayour"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.iman.marashi.makeupandbeauty.TextViewEx
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_margin="5dip"
        android:ellipsize="marquee"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine"
        android:text="txtDescription" />
</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>

<ImageView
android:id="@+id/ImageView01"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:src="@drawable/sep_line1" >
</ImageView>


</LinearLayout>
```

I found it, when i use TexView instead of TextViewEx,can fill completly to ScrollView, but whitout Justifying.

TextViewEx Code:

```
public class TextViewEx extends TextView {
private Paint paint = new Paint();
private String[] blocks;
private float spaceOffset = 0;
private float horizontalOffset = 0;
private float verticalOffset = 0;
private float horizontalFontOffset = 0;
private float dirtyRegionWidth = 0;
private boolean wrapEnabled = false;
int left, top, right, bottom = 0;
private Align _align = Align.RIGHT;
private float strecthOffset;
private float wrappedEdgeSpace;
private String block;
private String wrappedLine;
private String[] lineAsWords;
private Object[] wrappedObj;
public boolean hyphenate = false;
private String syllableSeparator = "";
private Bitmap cache = null;
private boolean cacheEnabled = false;

public TextViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    // set a minimum of left and right padding so that the texts are not too
    // close to the side screen
    this.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
}

public TextViewEx(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
}

public TextViewEx(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
}

@Override
public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {

    super.setPadding(left + 10, top, right + 10, bottom);
}

@Override
public void setDrawingCacheEnabled(boolean cacheEnabled) {
    this.cacheEnabled = cacheEnabled;
}

public void setText(String st, boolean wrap) {
    wrapEnabled = wrap;
    super.setText(st);
}

public void setTextAlign(Align align) {
    _align = align;
}

@SuppressLint({ "NewApi", "DrawAllocation" })
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    // If wrap is disabled then,
    // request original onDraw
    if (!wrapEnabled) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        return;
    }
    // Active canas needs to be set
    // based on cacheEnabled
    Canvas activeCanvas = null;
    // Set the active canvas based on
    // whether cache is enabled
    if (cacheEnabled) {
        if (cache != null) {
            // Draw to the OS provided canvas
            // if the cache is not empty
            canvas.drawBitmap(cache, 0, 0, paint);
            return;
        } else {
            // Create a bitmap and set the activeCanvas
            // to the one derived from the bitmap
            cache = Bitmap.createBitmap(getWidth(), getHeight(),
                    Config.ARGB_4444);
            activeCanvas = new Canvas(cache);
        }
    } else {
        // Active canvas is the OS
        // provided canvas
        activeCanvas = canvas;
    }
    // Pull widget properties
    paint.setColor(getCurrentTextColor());
    paint.setTypeface(getTypeface());
    paint.setTextSize(getTextSize());
    paint.setTextAlign(_align);
    paint.setFlags(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    // minus out the paddings pixel
    dirtyRegionWidth = getWidth() - getPaddingLeft() - getPaddingRight();
    int maxLines = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
    int currentapiVersion = android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT;
    if (currentapiVersion >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
        maxLines = getMaxLines();
    }
    int lines = 1;
    blocks = getText().toString().split("((?<=\n)|(?=\n))");
    verticalOffset = horizontalFontOffset = getLineHeight() - 0.5f; // Temp
                                                                    // fix
    spaceOffset = paint.measureText(" ");
    for (int i = 0; i < blocks.length && lines <= maxLines; i++) {
        block = blocks[i];
        horizontalOffset = 0;
        if (block.length() == 0) {
            continue;
        } else if (block.equals("\n")) {
            verticalOffset += horizontalFontOffset;
            continue;
        }
        block = block.trim();
        if (block.length() == 0) {
            continue;
        }
        wrappedObj = TextJustifyUtils
                .createWrappedLine(block, paint, spaceOffset,
                        dirtyRegionWidth, hyphenate, syllableSeparator);
        wrappedLine = ((String) wrappedObj[0]);
        wrappedEdgeSpace = (Float) wrappedObj[1];
        Integer charCounter = (Integer) wrappedObj[2];
        lineAsWords = wrappedLine.split(" ");
        strecthOffset = wrappedEdgeSpace != Float.MIN_VALUE ? wrappedEdgeSpace
                / (lineAsWords.length - 1)
                : 0;
        for (int j = 0; j < lineAsWords.length; j++) {
            String word = lineAsWords[j];
            if (lines == maxLines && j == lineAsWords.length - 1) {
                activeCanvas.drawText("...", horizontalOffset,
                        verticalOffset, paint);
            } else if (j == 0) {
                // if it is the first word of the line, text will be drawn
                // starting from right edge of textview
                if (_align == Align.RIGHT) {
                    activeCanvas.drawText(word, getWidth()
                            - (getPaddingRight()), verticalOffset, paint);
                    // add in the paddings to the horizontalOffset
                    horizontalOffset += getWidth() - (getPaddingRight());
                } else {
                    activeCanvas.drawText(word, getPaddingLeft(),
                            verticalOffset, paint);
                    horizontalOffset += getPaddingLeft();
                }
            } else {
                activeCanvas.drawText(word, horizontalOffset,
                        verticalOffset, paint);
            }
            if (_align == Align.RIGHT)
                horizontalOffset -= paint.measureText(word) + spaceOffset
                        + strecthOffset;
            else
                horizontalOffset += paint.measureText(word) + spaceOffset
                        + strecthOffset;
        }
        lines++;
        if (blocks[i].length() > 0) {
            blocks[i] = blocks[i].substring(charCounter);
            verticalOffset += blocks[i].length() > 0 ? horizontalFontOffset
                    : 0;
            i--;
        }
    }
    if (cacheEnabled) {
        // Draw the cache onto the OS provided
        // canvas.
        canvas.drawBitmap(cache, 0, 0, paint);
    }
}

public void setHyphenate(boolean hyphenate, String syllableSeparator) {
    this.hyphenate = hyphenate;
    this.syllableSeparator = syllableSeparator;
}
}
```

Comment: Please post the layout file, or the Java code where you assembled this view hierarchy.

Comment: Tank You @Justin Powell for your edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem by change this method:

```
@Override
public void setPadding(int left, int top, int right, int bottom) {
    DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources()
            .getDisplayMetrics();
    super.setPadding((int) ((left + (metrics.density * 10))), top,
            (int) (right + (metrics.density * 10)),
            (int) (bottom + (metrics.heightPixels * 1.5)));
    Log.i("Log", "metrics : " + metrics);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `ScrollView`'s height should be `match_parent`, ususally `Lint` should tell you so. 
If you set the height to `wrap_content`, the `ScrollView`  doesn't 'know' how tall it should be.

Comment: As an educational addendum: the reason is that ScrollView by definition will have a content height which differs from its display height, hence the scrolling. So the view's height shouldn't be relative to its content, but rather relative to some other aspect of the layout (such as matching its parent view's height).

Comment: I tested it, but the problem still remains.

Comment: That's odd. You might try removing the LinearLayout around the TextView, it doesn't really seem to serve a purpose.

Comment: @Ascorbin I tested it, but the problem still remains.

Comment: I would try to remove some of the attributres. Weightsum and weight would be my first candidates. Try to reduce the complexity as much as possible.

Comment: I solved it by adding more padding to the bottom

    TextViewEx.java:81
    super.setPadding(left+10, top, right+10, bottom+80);

Or

    DisplayMetrics metrics = getContext().getResources().getDisplayMetrics();
    super.setPadding((int)((left+(metrics.density * 10))), top, (int)(right+(metrics.density * 10)), (int) (bottom+(metrics.density * 40)));

Answer (score 0):

Try to change to this code:

```
<LinearLayout
android:id="@+id/DescribtionLinearLayour" 
android:layout_width="match_parent" 
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="vertical" >

<com.iman.marashi.makeupandbeauty.TextViewEx
        android:id="@+id/txtDescription" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent" 
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:layout_margin="5dip" 
        android:ellipsize="marquee" 
        android:gravity="right" 
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
        android:text="txtDescription" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I tested it, but the problem still remains.